# How to passdata from View to Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel like that:

```
    public class JobApplication
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyy-MM-dd}")]
        [Display(Name = "Edited on:")]
        public DateTime? EditedOn { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyy-MM-dd}")]
        [Display(Name = "Deleted on:")]
        public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }


        public User Applicant { get; set; }

        public JobOffer JobOffer { get; set; }

        public ApplicationStatus ApplicationStatus { get; set; }

        public string CvHandle { get; set; }
        public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
    }
```

The fields `JobOffer` and `Applicant` make it to the view correctly, so I can access them. However, I want to then pass them back to the `[HttpPost]` method in the Controller. So far I've tried using `Hidden` and `HiddenFor`:

```
@Html.Hidden("JobOffer", Model.JobOffer)
@Html.Hidden("Applicant", Model.Applicant)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Applicant)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.JobOffer)
```

But those don't work - all other values are mapped correctly when they make it to the Controller's method, but those are still `null`. How can I pass those values correctly back to the Controller with Post?

Comment: Show your controller method please. Plus `Model.JobOffer` will simply call `ToString()` and your view will have that and then post it back. Normally you post back stuff you get from the user and the rest you can just get from the db.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to make it work by created a dedicated ModelView for the JobApplication with a `JobOfferId` field that holds only the ID of the offer. Then I retrieve the `JobOffer` object in the controller by fetching from the db. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to store these values on server side, but if you indeed want to pass them through, you can use this format for each property of these objects:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Applicant.Field1)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Applicant.Field2)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.JobOffer.Field1)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.JobOffer.Field2)
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a good suggestion, but I ended up going server-side indeed, as per my comment to CodingYoshi's one.